# Microsoft graph send mail android java

Tags: java, android, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've been trying to send an email through an app that I've created in java but I'm getting 424 Error during Http request whenever I try to send the email I'm currently just using Microsoft's demo code for the request.

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

Message message = new Message();
message.subject = "Meet for lunch?";
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;
body.content = "The new cafeteria is open.";
message.body = body;
LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
emailAddress.address = "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;
LinkedList<Recipient> ccRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
Recipient ccRecipients = new Recipient();
EmailAddress emailAddress1 = new EmailAddress();
emailAddress1.address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
ccRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress1;
ccRecipientsList.add(ccRecipients);
message.ccRecipients = ccRecipientsList;

boolean saveToSentItems = false;

graphClient.me()
    .sendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .buildRequest()
    .post();
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error and how I fix this?

Thanks

Edit: here is the logcat

```
2020-07-17 16:12:22.744 4247-4247/com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf E/global: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 424Error during http request
2020-07-17 16:12:22.744 4247-4247/com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf E/global: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
2020-07-17 16:12:22.753 4247-4247/com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf, PID: 4247
    com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:422)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:306)
        at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.UserSendMailRequest.post(UserSendMailRequest.java:43)
        at com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf.MSoft.GraphHelper.sendEmail(GraphHelper.java:103)
        at com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf.Fragments.PreviewFragment$1$1.onSuccess(PreviewFragment.java:93)
        at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication.postAuthResult(PublicClientApplication.java:1659)
        at com.microsoft.identity.client.SingleAccountPublicClientApplication$4.onSuccess(SingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java:264)
        at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.ApiDispatcher$4$2.run(ApiDispatcher.java:433)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1598)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:426)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:789)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:777)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:750)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:57)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.isHealthy(RealConnection.java:561)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2020-07-17 16:12:22.756 4247-4247/com.brewski.servicecertificatepdf E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:356)
            ... 16 more
```

Comment: What is the full error message / stacktrace?

Comment: Added the logcat

Comment: *Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException* - you are not allowed to do this.